# Usage of Identity Server with ADFS

Tags: identity, claims-based-identity, adfs2.0, federated-identity

Currently my system is configured to get security tokens through identity server. We plan to change this to use ADFS and Identity server for authentication for AD users and others.

I need a workable code which makes calls to ADFS which intern invokes or calls identity server for users with forms authentication.

I went through many articles, but I am unable to code this logic. I may be missing something as I am new this concepts.

Appreciate your earliest response.

Answer (score 2):

You mean the open-source Identityserver?

If so, you don't need code. You just have to federate IdentityServer and ADFS.

On the ADFS side, this involves configuring IdentityServer as a Claims Provider and / or a RP - depending on who you want to use as IDP's.